# Android Studio problems switching themes

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I switched back and forth between the Dracula and Default theme. Now my text folder in the source set has a different color. How do I fix that? Tried invalidating the caches, restarting. But I couldn't fix it. Attached is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess - this folder is somehow *special*. It's either ignored (vcs), excluded etc. Check your color settings:

`File > Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > File Status` and look through the styles in your active scheme. One of those probably has a dark background set.

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix that from **File Colors** and that was where the background was set. I had no clue where to look before you answered this.